# How to load cordova.js asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So that I can develop on my machine and also my app seamlessly I'm loading cordova in with javascript.

As I'm a little stuck could this cause problems?

```
    if(SD.isMobile){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            Backbone.history.start();
            //Check to see if we are in the live app
            $.getScript('cordova.js', function(){
                $.getScript('http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#hutber');
                SD.checkConnection();
            });
        }, true);
    }else{
        $(document).ready(function() {
            Backbone.history.start();
            $.getScript('http://localhost:35729/livereload.js');
        });
    }
```

Also, worth noting I'm using phonegap version 3.0.0

Comment: Then the deviceready event is never fired I think http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html Dont know if it's required in app

Comment: interesting indeed, its version 3.0.0 btw :)

Comment: Same in 3.0.0 http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't that documentation say that deviceready gets fired once the cordova api is fully loaded?

Comment: Turned out it was a problem with the config.xml and there being 3 different versions in the phonegap build andriod folder.